# Wrong item from the listview is selected

Tags: android, listview

Initially it shows the correct item selected...but after re-populating the list it shows the wrong item being selected...please help me find the mistake

Intially the list is populated in onCreate()
and is re-populated in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyListActivity adapter;
    ListView list;

    String[] web = {
            "jerry",
            "walters"
    } ;
    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher      
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adapter = new MyListActivity(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_settings:
                String[] web2 = {
                        "walters",
                        "jerry"
                } ;
                adapter = new MyListActivity(MainActivity.this, web2, imageId);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: try this...

switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_settings:
            String[] web2 = {
                    "walters",
                    "jerry"
            } ;
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            adapter = new MyListActivity(MainActivity.this, web2, imageId);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            return true;
    }

Comment: You have this

     `web[position]` // always displays from  web string array not from web2

Comment: yea...the problem was the two different arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this

```
 web[position]
 // get string from  web string array not from web2 based on position
```

Position is the index.

```
web[0] = "jerry"
web[1] ="walters"
```

You are re-populating your listview with a different array.

`web` and `web2` are two different arrays.

If you want to update , update the web array and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter to refresh listview

Answer (score 0):

your are not updating your web array:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyListActivity adapter;
    ListView list;

    String[] web = {
            "jerry",
            "walters"
    } ;
    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher      
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adapter = new MyListActivity(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_settings:
                web = {//<--------------just update we array as well
                        "walters",
                        "jerry"
                } ;
                adapter = new MyListActivity(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might because web and web2 have different order which leads to different answer?

```
    String[] web = { "jerry", "walters"} ; 

    String[] web2 = {"walters", "jerry" } ;
```