# ListView custom filter gives wrong item selected when filtered

Tags: android, listview, filter

I am new to Android programming and I have a ListView when filtered always return me the first item in the list, so how do I fix this?

For instance, my list contains A.A, A.B, A.C, B.C, B.D. When I want to search the list for things starting with B, I will get B.C, B.D but when I click B.C, it returns me A.A and B.D, it returns me A.B

I am weeks I'm looking for a solution! please help me !!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView lv;
SearchView search_view;

String[] country_names , iso_codes ;
TypedArray country_flags ;

ArrayList<Country> countrylist ;
CustomAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    search_view = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    country_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_names);
    iso_codes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.iso_Code);
    country_flags = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.country_flags);

    countrylist = new ArrayList<Country>();
    for (int i = 0; i < country_names.length; i++) {
        Country country = new Country(country_names[i] , iso_codes[i] ,
                country_flags.getResourceId(i, -1) );
        countrylist.add(country);
    }

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), countrylist );
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);










}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.i("HelloListView", "You clicked Item: " + id + " at position:" + position);
    // Then you start a new Activity via Intent
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, ListItemDetail.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);
    // Or / And
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

list item detail

```
public class ListItemDetail extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item_detail);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);

    // Here we turn your string.xml in an array
    String[] myKeys = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sections);
    String[] myKeys2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testo2);

    String[] myKeys3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testo3);

    String[] myKeys4 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testo4);



    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
    myTextView.setText(myKeys[position]);

    TextView myTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testo2);
    myTextView2.setText(myKeys2[position]);

    TextView myTextView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testo3);
    myTextView3.setText(myKeys3[position]);

    TextView myTextView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testo4);
    myTextView4.setText(myKeys4[position]);
```

customlistAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

Context context;
ArrayList<Country> countrylist;
ArrayList<Country> mStringFilterList;
ValueFilter valueFilter;



CustomAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<Country> countrylist) {
    this.context = context;
    this.countrylist = countrylist;
    mStringFilterList = countrylist;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return countrylist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return countrylist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return countrylist.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent ) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        TextView name_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView iso_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        Country country = countrylist.get(position);

        name_tv.setText(country.getName());
        iso_tv.setText(country.getIso_code());



        Picasso
                .with(context)
                .load(url[position])
                .fit() // will explain later
                .centerCrop()
                .into(iv);
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (valueFilter == null) {
        valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}

private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Country> filterList = new ArrayList<Country>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                if ( (mStringFilterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase() )
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                    Country country = new Country(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                            .getName() ,  mStringFilterList.get(i)
                            .getIso_code() ,  mStringFilterList.get(i)
                            .getFlag());

                    filterList.add(country);
                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        } else {
            results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
            results.values = mStringFilterList;
        }
        return results;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  FilterResults results) {
        countrylist = (ArrayList<Country>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

contry

```
public class Country {

String name;
String iso_code;
int flag;

Country(String name, String iso_code, int flag) {
    this.name = name;
    this.iso_code = iso_code;
    this.flag = flag;
}

public String getIso_code() {
    return iso_code;
}

public void setIso_code(String iso_code) {
    this.iso_code = iso_code;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getFlag() {

    return flag;
}

public void setFlag(int flag) {

    this.flag = flag;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice you're using the position as input to the `ListItemDetail` activity.  This will cause you problems as the position for a given item will change as the list is filtered.

You should just put the item values into the `Intent` then use those values and not look anything up in `ListItemDetail`

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Country country = (Country) ((CustomAdapter ) l.getAdapter()).getItem(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListItemDetail.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", country.getName());
    intent.putExtra("iso_code", country.getIso_code());
    intent.putExtra("flag", country.getFlag());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now change your `ListDetailActivity` to use these values:

```
public class ListItemDetail extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item_detail);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String iso_code = intent.getStringExtra("iso_code");
        int flagResId = intent.getIntExtra("flag");

        // make a TextView in activity_list_item_detail.xml called "name"
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        nameTextView .setText(name);

        // make a TextView in activity_list_item_detail.xml called "iso_code"
        TextView isoCodeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.iso_code);
        isoCodeTextView .setText(iso_code);

        // make an ImageView in activity_list_item_detail.xml called "flag" 
        ImageView flagImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag);
        flagImageView.setImageResource(flagResId);
    }
}
```

Note this activity won't work until you update your activity_list_item_detail.xml as suggested in the comments

Comment: thanks for comment!! i writ this but when oper the item the app show always the same string (1)

Comment: Country country = (Country) ((CustomAdapter ) l.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("title", country.getName());

Comment: Please post the code for your CustomAdapter, also your Country class

Comment: i add customadapter and country. thansk for help!

Comment: i see that ListItemDetail required a int not a string.  (getName is a string). i create getTitle  with int in Country but the app crash with this error   "Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=-1"

Comment: You ListItemDetail activity is still depending on the position, and that is what is causing your problems.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: thanks!!! this work!! but there is an error in "int flagResId = intent.getIntExtra("flag");" in intent cannot be applied to string.                       another information..  therefore any text or image you want to send in the activity I have to pass strings before then in the Country Main activity and then in ListItemDetail ?? or is there any other way ??? thank you very much for your help !!!

Comment: If you put in all the code to make your `Country` class implement `Parcelable`, you could put the entire `Country` object in the intent so you don't have to pass all kinds of strings.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable  But the main point here is that position is useless as a value to another activity when you are filtering your list.